# Does moveTo consider public ramparts walkable?

Tags: javascript, screeps

Does `Creep.moveTo` or `Room.findPath` consider public Ramparts as walkable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note - I've only looked at the [code](https://github.com/screeps/engine) branches dealing with the [new pathfinder](http://support.screeps.com/hc/en-us/articles/207023879-PathFinder). So here are my findings:

`creep.MoveTo` uses `pos.findPathTo` to generate a path, which in turn uses `room.FindPath`.

`room.FindPath` calls a private function, `_findPath2` which, using `getPathfindingGrid2` and `makePathfindingGrid2`, obtains a cost matrix for the room. In [line 176 of rooms.js](https://github.com/screeps/engine/blob/master/src/game/rooms.js#L176) ramparts that are **not** public have their cost set to 0xFF, rendering them unwalkable for the purposes of path finding.

So it seems that public ramparts are walkable.